# Wiring Ecobee thermostat to Vulkan gas furnace with no C terminal

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I am trying to wire up an Ecobee thermostat to an old (1997) Gas central heating system but I got up into the roof then realised I have no terminal labelled C.

Now, I don't super know what I am doing, but based on the diagram taken from the heater I should in theory be able to tap into the wire on the right side (to the left of the earths) that is labelled 24VAC?

[image: No C terminal]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

[image]

is the equivalent of the "C" terminal.  Get it from here:

[image]

Comment: Really? Seems counterintuitive to me i thought it would have been the 24vac labelled thing to the left of that. So i have to find the specific wire in the ground section that comes out of the 24v transformer?

Comment: After reading some more, this is making more sense to me now :D

Comment: This worked perfectly. Pulled the blue wire from the top centre of the ground section off and created a little extension using some blade connectors and a short section of wire, and tapped the ecobee power extension kit into that.